# SQL query to find rows that don't have a 1 to 1 relationship between 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given two columns (Animal and Name) how do I write a SQL statement that finds the rows that don't have a 1 to 1 relationship i.e. Dog = Patch and Dog = Rover ?

| Animal | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Dog | Patch |
| Cat | Sylvester |
| Mouse | Gerry |
| Mouse | Gerry |
| Dog | Rover |

Comment: I think you misunderstand what a relationship is...

Comment: what result do you want?

Comment: Perhaps mapping would be a better choice of wording...

Comment: I want Dog = Patch and Dog = Rover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `EXISTS` operator with a correlated subquery as the following:

```
SELECT Animal, Name
FROM table_name T
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_name D WHERE D.Animal=T.Animal AND D.Name<>T.Name)
ORDER BY Animal
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/TX_SJhn9).

Comment: Thanks Ahmed this works, please let me know if my question could be worded better although it seem you had no problem figuring it out. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome, the problem is with using the sentence `1 to 1 relationship` ,  for example, you could say *how to find rows that have multiple names for the same animal within the same table*.

Comment: *A relationship between two database tables presupposes that one of them has a foreign key that references the primary key of another table.*

Comment: I agree I could have worded it better

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work (probably not the best way to do it):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Animal, Name
FROM (
  SELECT Animal, Name, COUNT(DISTINCT Name) OVER (PARTITION BY Animal) NamesPerAnimal
  FROM Table
  UNION
  SELECT Animal, Name, COUNT(DISTINCT Animal) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) AnimalsPerName
  FROM Table
)
WHERE NamesPerAnimal > 1 OR AnimalsPerName > 1
```

This looks the number of distinct Animal values for each Name anywhere in the table and vice versa and returns only the rows where one or the other is greater than 1.